# Save ActiveRecord with related model

Tags: php, yii2

I have table TASK related to USER as many-to-one relationship.And i have ActiveRecords Task and TodoUser. So when i am creating Task i need to attach User to it and save Task. Hy code looks like this
`

```
    $model = new Task();
    $user = TodoUser::findOne(['ID'=>Yii::$app->user->id]);
    $model->populateRelation('USER',$user);
    //load attrs into model and validate
    $model->save();
```

`
But Yii throws error

`cannot insert NULL into ("TODO"."TASK"."USER") The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO "TASK" ("NAME", "DESCRIPTION") VALUES ('todo', 'to do todo')  RETURNING "ID" INTO :qp2`

User fetches properly, and after populateRelation() in $model it appears in relations. It seems like it tries to save only Task model. So what is the way to do it properly to get sql look like this: `INSERT INTO "TASK" ("NAME", "DESCRIPTION","USER") VALUES ('todo', 'to do todo',1) RETURNING "ID" INTO :qp2`

Thanks for help!

Comment: Look into this part of the docs a bit for saving related models https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#saving-relations

Answer (score 0):

```
$model->USER=$user->id;
```

instead of

```
$model->populateRelation('USER',$user);
```

answers my question. But is it god solution of problem?